# Нельзя начать компиляцию из-за ошибки "Внешний путь не подходит для модуля"

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: Ошибка компиляции, собственно]

Установил Intellij Idea на второй комп. Скачиваю свой проект с гитхаба. А мне выдает вот такую ошибку компиляции:

> путь не подходит для модуля

Причем на домашнем моем компьютере всё запускается. В конфигурацию проекта лазил, галки уже по всякому переставлял. 
[image: Конфигурация проекта]
Подскажите пожалуйста, как сие безобразие исправить? (и чем оно вызвано?).

Comment: Поставь галку Use module compile output path и выставь путь

Comment: Не "не подходит", а "не задан".

Comment: И не "внешний", а "выходной" или "результирующий".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Путь задаётся в свойствах проекта.
Вероятно, сейчас поле пустое. Заполните его:

`{путь к каталогу проекта}/out`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]